# How to copy from a sheet to another sheet excel?

Tags: excel, function

So, I have a Sheet1, with a header called "Domain" (A1) and under it I have a number (in A2). I have another sheet, called Sheet2, where I have just (A1) the header, called "Domain". I need a formula to copy what is under "Domain" meaning, to copy from A2, to what is under "Domain" in my Sheet2, to (A2).

I've tried to use the VLOOKUP function, and CONCATENATE, but something is missing. Could somebody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually perform the copy you would use a macro rather than a formula:

```
Sub CopyCell()
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Copy Sheet2.Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: still, wasn't able to make it really working for what I wanted, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If A2 in sheet2 is always going to equal A2 in sheet1 why not just do:

```
='Sheet1'!A2
```

Granted if the value in sheet 1 changes the value in sheet2 will change as well.